# Query and subquery in symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I use query and subquery in **symfony** query builder, but when execute it, it returns an error.

My code is :

```
 $subQb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

            $subquery = $subQb->select('COUNT(v.id)')
                ->from('AdminBundle:Visitsite', 'v')
                ->where('v.site = s.id')
                ->Andwhere('v.createdate > :date')
                ->setParameter('date', $date->format('Y-m-d'))
                ->getDQL();

            $subQb2 = $em->createQueryBuilder();
            $subquery2 = $subQb2->select('quantity')
                ->from('AdminBundle:Limitviewday', 'l')
                ->where($subQb2->expr()->eq('s.limitviewday', 'l.id'))
                ->getDQL();

            $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
            $query = $qb->select('s')
                ->from('AdminBundle:Sites', 's')
                ->where('s.quantity > 1')
                ->Andwhere('s.status = 1')
                ->Andwhere($qb->expr()->lte("($subquery)", "($subquery2)"));

            $settlements = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

And my result is

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 183 near 'quantity FROM': Error: 'quantity' is not defined.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that error come from:

```
$subquery2 = $subQb2->select('quantity') // Expected '<alias>' or '<alias>.<property>'
```

instead:

```
$subquery2 = $subQb2->select('l.quantity')
```